# Eigen solve symmetric positive definite system using LLT

Tags: c++, math, linear-algebra, eigen

I want to solve a symmetric positive definite matrix using the LLT solver, to that effect I wrote this (to test):

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<float> bijection(vert_count, vert_count);
Eigen::LLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<Scalar>> llt_mat(bijection);
```

This fails to compile with error:

```
error: ‘Eigen::SparseMatrixBase<Eigen::Block<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 0, int>, -1, 1, true> >::FixedSegmentReturnType<-1>::Type’ {aka ‘class Eigen::VectorBlock<Eigen::Block<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 0, int>, -1, 1, true>, -1>’} has no member named ‘lpNorm’
  448 |       abs_col_sum = m_matrix.col(col).tail(size - col).template lpNorm<1>() + m_matrix.row(col).head(col).template lpNorm<1>();
```

I am not entirely sure how I should solve a system using the built in LLT solver.

Comment: You need to use one of the sparse solvers: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicSparseSystems.html

Comment: this works, thank you